# Syntax Analyzer in c#

Tags: c#, context-free-grammar

I have given the project to make the syntax analyzer using any programming language. I am doing it in C#. The simple context free grammar has been created. But now i am very confuse to make algorithm for the syntax analyzer.

The grammar is like that:

```
    Namespace       var . { class }
    Class           var . { method  } . class | null
    Method          function | null
    Function        return_type.var.(function_arguements).{.stmt_list.} . Method
                    .......... and so on
```

I have to show the errors, and line numbers for the errors as well. I need some guidance to even start coding. I tried 2D-arrays, linked lists, enumerations, structures. But i could not create any good algorithm for this.

Comment: I suggest you find a good compiler design text book and read it. There are also a couple of nice articles on this matter: http://www.pling.org.uk/cs/lsa.html & http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/course/2002/nand2tet/docs/ch_10_compiler_I.pdf But what you need to do is define a grammar, get the code tokenized and start analyzing the tokens and the order they come in.

Answer (score 2):

When I took compiler, we had to write a compiler for a simple language. I don't know if I follow exactly your language definition in your question or how far you have gotten, but this is the approach we used when parsing our language.

First, you need a lexical analyzer class, that is only responsible for getting the next token in the input. This essentially marched through the code and with each call, `GetNextToken()` returns the next string in the code. So say you had the following line of code:

```
PROCEDURE sum() RETURN INTEGER;
```

The first call to `GetNextToken()` would return `PROCEDURE`. The second call would return `sum`, third would return `(` then `)` then `RETURN`, `INTEGER`, and finally `;`

Now you need a Syntax Parser. The idea is that your language definition should eventually hit a terminating token. Here is a small snippit of my compiler language definition:

```
<program> -> $UNIT <prog-identifier> $SEMICOLON
                   <block> $PERIOD
<block> -> [<label-declaration>]
                   {<variable-dec-sec>}*
                   {<procedure-declaration>}*
                   $LEFTBRACE <statement> {$SEMICOLON <statement>}*
                   $RIGHTBRACE
```

So in the analyzer we call a function `Program()`. `Program()` would get the next token. If that token was `UNIT` we would get the would call another function, `ProgIdentifier()` which would again call `GetNextToken()`. `ProgramIdentifier()` would look for an identifier type. Moving on in `Program()`, see if the next token is a `;`. Then call `Block()` which works in the same way as `Program()` and then see if you have a `.` after.

The key is that at each ending token, for example, the `;`, you would have an `if` statement. So the simple code for `Program()` might look like this:

```
public int Program()
{
    lex.GetNextToken();
        if (lex.InternalCode == TokenTable.UNIT)
        {
            lex.GetNextToken();
            ProgIdentifier();
            if (lex.InternalCode == TokenTable.SEMICOLON)
            {
                lex.GetNextToken();
                Block();
                if (parseErrors)
                {
                    //Drop out into Statement Level Parsing
                    //Statement Level Parsing just calls Statement() for <statement>
                    //until you have gone through the entire input.
                    //The point is to avoid getting many errors if you are missing a
                    //single token.
                    StatementLevelParse();
                }
                if (lex.InternalCode == TokenTable.PERIOD)
                {
                    lex.GetNextToken();
                    if (lex.EndOfFile)
                    {
                        if (!parseFailed)
                        {
                            //Success
                            echo("Success");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo("Parse Failed");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Error(lex.CurrentLine, 200, false, "Expected End Of File: Found " + lex.NextSymbol);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Fail. Expected $PERIOD
                    Error(lex.CurrentLine, 200, false, "Expected \".\": Found " + lex.NextSymbol);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Fail. Expected $SEMICOLON
                Error(lex.CurrentLine, 200, false, "Expected \";\": Found " + lex.NextSymbol);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Fail. Expected $UNIT
            Error(lex.CurrentLine, 200, false, "Expected \"UNIT\": Found " + lex.NextSymbol);
        }
        EchoOutput("LEAVING PROGRAM");
        return 0;
}
```

I see now that it is a lot to read. I am not sure if this is the approach your instructor wants you take or not, but I found it very simple and easy to implement if you understand your language. I make no guarantees that this is the most effective or efficient way to doing this, just the method I was required to use.

I really hope I understood your question correctly...